# Bucharian Nusach; Nusach Sfard

Tags: nuschaot, nusach-sefard

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90265/may-a-shul-change-its-nusach).

Why do the Bucharian communities use Nusach Sfard, the Hasidic nusach? Shouldn't they use a variation of the Mizrahi nusach, or perhaps some variation on Nusach Ashkenaz?

Surely, they must have used a different nusach before the founding of the Hasidic Movement in the late Eighteenth Century - what nusach did they use before?

Why do Bucharian communities use Nusach Sfard today, and what did they use before?

<sup>Perhaps I am grossly misunderstanding and [DanF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5275/danf) meant to say "Nusach Sepharad" and Bucharians do not use the Hasidic nusach at all.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that they use "Nuasch Sepharad" due to 18th century Rabbi Yosef ben Moshe Mammon (Maimon) Maravi deciding to move to Bhukara (from his native Morocco) and teach them in the face of severly declining observence, wikipedia description here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Maimon

Comment: So they use Nusach Sepharad, not Nusach "Sfard".

Comment: Correct, @ezra....I spell that particular word out in Spanish far more often than in English